# How do I fight spam against my mail servers?

Tags: spam-prevention, mailing-list

The problem I am having is the ability to fight spammers who add `unsubscribe from this mail list by clicking here` into their spam emails. Turns out I am not the only one to suffer from this, Gmail doesn't filter these mails.

I made a simple test case, created an email on Gmail and contacted one of the spammers asking him to add my address to his list (such a bad idea  :P) and Google thought that I am already subscribed to that list and put it in my inbox.
These kind of spammers use many accounts to send their spam which make this job much harder.

How do I report these spammers, and block them in Gmail or mail mail servers?

What is the fastest way to do that?

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is here. Is it that GMail let the e-mail into your inbox despite it being flagged as spam or from an address on your blacklist?

Comment: My idea is 'repost spam' isn't enough , for example one spammer changes its email address from noreply@example.com to noreply2@example.com and still able to send spams to gmail + local mail server

Answer (score 2):

Use the "Report spam" button and won't worry. In time, Gmail figures out who is who.